# Explorer image thumbnail association

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, thumbnails, images

Is there a way to add new file types to Windows explorer thumbnail view?

I have some files that are simply images with a non-standard extention (don't ask!) - is there any way to tell Explorer that these are really just jpegs and it should generate thumbnails as if they were jpegs?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, how about using Associate - you can download it here: http://www.vtaskstudio.com/support.php#tools it's tiny and portable.

```
Associate is a command-line utility for assigning file associations. 
This will allow you to double-click a file and have it 
load in the appropriate program. 
It also includes the ability to set a file type icon and startup parameters, 
and it automatically refreshes Explorer. Type "associate -?" for details. 

Syntax:       associate [extension] [program] 
Example:     associate .txt %WINDIR%\notepad.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah:

Click on Tools - Folder Options - File Types - Then click on New. In the extension box put the extension. Click on advanced, and then select "Jpeg Image" as the file type.

Comment: Sorry for being dumb, I'm on win7 I don't have a File types in explorer.

Comment: I suggested a different way below. I've tested it in XP, but I don't have a copy of Windows 7, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, didn't realise it was Windows 7.

Have to admit, I'm no Windows 7 expert. Could you write this in a text document, save it as "import.reg" and double click it to add it to the registry? It works in XP.

Just replace "YOUREXTENSION" with the extension you're trying to add?

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.YOUREXTENSION]
"PerceivedType"="image"
@="jpegfile"
"Content Type"="image/jpeg"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.YOUREXTENSION\OpenWithProgids]
"jpegfile"=hex(0):


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.YOUREXTENSION\PersistentHandler]
@="{098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"
```

Comment: Doesn't work on win7 unfortunately. Will post a solution when I find one