# Thumbnail preview for custom file extension with known format

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, thumbnails

I have a file named `test.png`. Windows 10 shows a thumbnail preview in file explorer just fine.

I'd like to rename it to `test.abc` and have the thumbnail preview still work.

Following [forcing thumbnail preview for custom file format](https://superuser.com/a/939785/381191) (which was for Win 7) hasn't worked. I get a default thumbnail.

Copying the registry entry for `.png` and editing in the different extension hasn't worked. Again, default thumbnail.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.abc]
@="pngfile"
"Content Type"="image/png"
"PerceivedType"="image"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.abc\OpenWithProgids]
"AppX43hnxtbyyps62jhe9sqpdzxn1790zetc"=hex(0):
"AppXcdh38jxzbcberv50vxg2tg4k84kfnewn"=hex(0):
"LibreOffice.Png"=" "
"pngfile"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.abc\PersistentHandler]
@="{098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"
```

Is something different in windows 10? Some additional step I'm missing? Something I don't understand?